# How to do operation on each queue assigned to each process parallel in python?

Tags: python, concurrency, queue

Lets say there is four core cpu processor and I am running all four process. To each process, I assigned a queue. But how do i run all queue concurrently.

```
class ParentProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            data = self.queue.get()
            print(data)

def main():
   numProcs = 4
   queueList = [multiprocessing.Queue() for i in range(numProcs)]

   for index, queue in enumerate(queueList):
        deals = [1,2,3]
        for deal in deals:
            queue.put(deal)
        p = ParentProcess(queue)
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Here each process runs one by one. But,
i need to run this parallely and work on each element of queue parallely.

Comment: Why do you say that it is not running in parallel? Your queue is so short that you wouldn't see any difference. Setting up the process takes more time than running your queue. Increase the workload by factor 1000 or more to see real differences.

Comment: To show in the example, I have added only three elements but in actual code, the queue is around 500 to 1000 elements in size. 

the code completes first by dequeuing from one process and once that queue empties, another queue from another process starts.

Comment: It's still a problem of timing. You fill 1st queue, start 1st process and repeat. So while you set up 2nd process, the 1st queue is most likely already empty. So start you processes first and fill the queues afterward. Or fill all queues first and then start the processes.